# Access Violation when dealing with large files that cannot be mapped to one view in Win32

Tags: c++, windows

Good morning, I am trying to write a cMemoryMappedFile class that deals with large files that cannot be mapped to one view in Win32. The code is at the [pastebin url](http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=teuGB43x).

In GetPointer(), we are trying to carefully map and unmap file regions as they are needed. We are encountering an access violation in GetPointer() on the line marked with the comment // crashes here if adjusted ptr is bad ptr.

The test program is:

```
int TotalKeys = 2709783;
try {
    mmapFile = new cMemoryMappedFile(TotalKeys * 54 + 1);   
}
catch (cException e) {
    printf("catch cMemoryMappedFile\n");
    throwl     
}

for (i = 0; i < 50000; i++) {
    mmapFile->GetPointer(i * 54);
}
```

When i equals 28521 and i * 54 = 1540134, we get an access violation reading location 0x0024000. The MEM_BLOCK_SIZE is on the 64K alignment required by MapViewOfFile, MEM_BLOCK_SIZE = 65536 * 2. We are running Windows XP Professional Version 2002 Service Pack 3, 32 bit version. What is puzzling is that we are trying the move the map view within the file mapping. Please suggest the cause of the access violation if you wish.

Thank you.

Comment: Please use the `{}` button to fix your formatting...

Comment: @bdonlan, Could you please tell me where the {} button is so I can fix my formatting? Thank you.

Comment: I think 300+ lines of code is too much; try to reduce the amount of code to only that which is necessary or use something like pastebin.com.

Comment: Have you tried reading this? Me neither!

Comment: @Luke, I apologize for not using www.pastebin.com. I don't know if you can paste pastebin.com urls in StackOverflow posts. Here is the pastebin.url for source code and header file: <iframe src="http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=teuGB43x" style="border:none;width:100%"></iframe>

Comment: @Luke, Should I start a new post with the pastebin.com url? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: just edit your post so that only the question and the pastebin URL are in it.  Don't start a new post.

Comment: @Andre, StackOverflow.com just edited the post to include only the question and the pastebin URL. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This calculation seems overly complicated.

```
char * cMemoryMappedFile::GetPointer(int n){
    unsigned int baseoff;
    if( n < MEM_BLOCK_SIZE / 2)
    {
       baseoff = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        baseoff = ((n + MEM_BLOCK_SIZE / 4) &
           (~(MEM_BLOCK_SIZE / 2 - 1))) - MEM_BLOCK_SIZE / 2;
    }
    ...
```

As I understand, `n` is the desired offset into the file, and `baseoff` is the first address we'll actually map.  We want the largest `baseoff` <= `n`, where `baseoff` is a multiple of `MEM_BLOCK_SIZE`.  So how about:

```
    unsigned int baseoff = (n / MEM_BLOCK_SIZE) * MEM_BLOCK_SIZE;
```

Later:

```
    MapPtr = (char*)::MapViewOfFile(hMapping, FILE_MAP_WRITE | FILE_MAP_READ, 0,
                    baseoff, mappedlength);
```

You should check the result of `MapViewOfFile`.

It's not clear what you want the return value to be.  I'm assuming `adjustedptr + n` should point to the originally requested byte.  But then you try to access `*adjustedptr`, which is not guaranteed to be part of the view when the base offset is larger than `MEM_BLOCK_SIZE`. I think you want the printf to use `*(adjustedptr + n)` or `adjustedptr[n]`.  Or maybe you're trying to access the first byte actually mapped, which would be `adjustedptr[baseoff]`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try your suggestions as soon as possible and I will let you know the result. It is an excellent analysis. If I could you 5 votes, I would, Thank you

Comment: I tested your suggestions. When n = 65610, the Microsoft operator delete[] returns a DEBUG_ASSERTION_FAILED _CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData). Here is the www.pastebin url for the code snippet showing where Microsoft complains about the operaror delete. <iframe src="http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=mvmxLa62" style="border:none;width:100%"></iframe>. I used valgrind on Centos Unix a week ago to test for heap corruption in this code snippet and valgrind didn't report any heap errors. Maybe this problem is unique to Microsoft.

Comment: I just accepted your answer. Could you think of a workaround to this Microsoft operator delete [] probem? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 I fixed the access violation and the Microsoft operator delete error. The modified code is in the www.pastebin.com url.<iframe src="http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=4dsVfkzg" style="border:none;width:100%"></iframe> > I wish to thank Adrian
```

McCarthy and Andre Caron for their help.